# Idioms or phrases to describe continuous occurrence of bad things

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Are there any idioms or phrases to describe a continuous occurrence of bad things, but after a lapse of time. For instance, a man was killed, leaving his wife and son. Few months later, the wife was diagnosed with cancer. And after a year, her son passed away.

I am thinking of using the idiom **it never rains but it pours**. But i have also read
on stackexchange that this idiom is better suiting a scenario where bad things happen one after the other in a quick succession

Comment: There is a saying "bad things happen in threes" which would work in this particular case.

Comment: *Family curse*.

Answer (score 2):

This chain of bad things is called "a series of unfortunate events" or you can say "that person is ***dogged by misfortune***".

> **be dogged by misfortune** (=have a lot of bad luck over a period of time)
>
> The project seemed dogged by misfortune.
>
> [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/misfortune#:%7E:text=COLLOCATIONSverbssuffer%20misfortuneYou,project%20seemed%20dogged%20by%20misfortune.)

Comment: Yes, this is excellent. +1

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Yours is good too. I learned a new idiom "a run of bad luck"! (always love learning new things)

Answer (score 1):

The family had a terrible **run of bad luck**.

The Johnson's suffered a disastrous run of bad luck.

> **a run of bad luck**
> A period of continuous misfortune. I've just had a
> run of bad luck lately. After losing my job, I found out that I won't
> be entitled to any social welfare payments while I look for work. She
> broke up with him? Wow, the poor guy's run of bad luck continues.
> https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+of+bad+luck